# Is my s3 bucket set to the correct region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I go to console in AWS by clicking the yellow cube in the top corner it directs me to the following url:

```
https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=ap-southeast-1
```

> This is correct, cause my app is used primarily in Southeast Asia.

Now when I go to my S3 bucket, right click and select properties, I see:

```
Bucket: examplebucket
Region: US Standard
```

I believe that when I first created my AWS account I had set it to `us-west-2`  and then later changed it to `ap-southeast-1`. Is there something I need to do is change the region of the s3 bucket from `'US Standard'`?

In the navbar, under global it says `"S3 does not require region selection."` which is confusing to me.

The bucket is being used for photo storage. The majority of my web users are in Southeast Asia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would certainly make sense to locate the bucket closest to the majority of your users. Also, consider using Amazon CloudFront to cache objects, providing even faster data access to your users.

Each Amazon S3 bucket resides in a **single region**. Any data placed into that bucket stays within that region. It is also possible to configure **cross-region replication** of buckets, which will copy objects from one bucket to a different bucket in a different region.

The Amazon S3 management console **displays all buckets in all regions** (hence the message that "S3 does not require region selection"). Clicking on a bucket will display the bucket properties, which will show the region in which the bucket resides.

It is not possible to 'change' the region of a bucket. Instead, you should create a new bucket in the desired region and **copy the objects to the new bucket**. The easiest way to copy the files is via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), with a command like:

```
 aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket s3://destination-bucket --recursive
```

If you have many files, it might be safer to use the `sync` option, which can be run multiple times (in case of errors/failures):

```
aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://destination-bucket
```

Please note that if you wish to **retain the name of the bucket,** you would need to copy to a temporary bucket, delete the original bucket, wait for the bucket name to become available again (10 minutes?), create the bucket in the desired region, then copy the objects to the new bucket.